# Cross image on SWT.CHECK

Tags: java, swt

I want to display to user that a check box cannot be selected. I have made it greyed, but I wanted to show a cross (X) in the check box instead of default tick) on selecting.

Is there a way to show cross mark in the check box when it is selected.

Answer (score 3):

SWT `Widget`s are OS dependent, meaning that the OS determines what they look like.

Consequently, there is no way of making a `Button` show a "X" without considerable coding on your side.

Your best option would be to [create a completely new `Widget` based on `Composite` or `Canvas`](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm) and do the painting completely yourself.